# G29 Sometimes fails - Defective probe?

Tags: bltouch

I have the issue that `G29` does work as expected but then fails a couple of times at different measuring points after taht it succeeds again.

So I decided to enable debugging for leveling by `M111 S32`:

```
Recv: <<< do_blocking_move_to  X291.1250 Y96.0000 Z1.1500
Recv:   current_position= X291.1250 Y96.0000 Z1.1499 : sync_plan_position
Recv: <<< Probe::probe_down_to_z  X291.1250 Y96.0000 Z1.1499
Recv:  Probe fail! - No trigger.
Recv: <<< Probe::run_z_probe  X291.1250 Y96.0000 Z1.1499
Recv:   current_position= X291.1250 Y96.0000 Z1.1499 : Probe::set_deployed
Recv: deploy=0 no_return=0
Recv: Raise Z to 5.0000
Recv: do_z_clearance(5.0000 [1.1499 to 7.1500], 0)
Recv: do_blocking_move_to_z(7.1500, 4.1667)
Recv: >>> do_blocking_move_to  X291.1250 Y96.0000 Z1.1499
Recv: >  X291.1250 Y96.0000 Z7.1500
[...]
Recv: <<< do_blocking_move_to  X291.1250 Y96.0000 Z7.1500
Recv: >>> Probe::probe_specific_action  X291.1250 Y96.0000 Z7.1500
Recv: BLTouch STOW requested
Recv: BLTouch from 10 to 90
Recv: bltouch.stow_proc() end
Recv: <<< Probe::probe_specific_action  X291.1250 Y96.0000 Z7.1500
Recv: >>> do_blocking_move_to  X291.1250 Y96.0000 Z7.1500
Recv: >  X291.1250 Y96.0000 Z7.1500
Recv: <<< do_blocking_move_to  X291.1250 Y96.0000 Z7.1500
Recv: //action:notification Probing Failed
Recv: Error:Probing Failed
WARNING! Received an error from the printer's firmware, ignoring that as configured but you might want to investigate what happened here! Error: Probing Failed
```

Does `Probe fail! - No trigger.` mean the probe has a defect so that it sometimes does not trigger?

Comment: Is this a genuine BLTouch? Or a Creality kind of clone? I've used various clones, but none match the original product, those never failed me. I've given up the clones, I had exactly similar issues.

Comment: I think it is. It came with the printer (ender 5 plus) and until recently it worked fine. I did change the pin though, maybe it's a bad one? I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the probe to a CR-10 model. The one with the metal pin. No Issues anymore. I didn't even change the wire. So either the probe or the pin was bad. ‍♂️